# Solarium Highlighting using an array configuration

Tags: solarium

This query works for me.

```
   $hl = $query->getHighlighting();
   $hl->setFields('autocomplete');
   $hl->setSimplePrefix('');
   $hl->setSimplePostfix('');

   $resultSet = $client->select($query);
   $highlighting = $resultSet->getHighlighting();
```

However,the following doesn't seem to work.

```
   $main_query = 'autocomplete:'.$autocomplete;
   $select = array(
          'query' => $main_query,
          'rows'  => 1000,
          'component' => array('highlighting' => array('fields' =>'autocomplete')));

   $query = $client->createSelect($select);
   $resultSet = $client->select($query);
   $highlighting = $resultSet->getHighlighting();
```

What is that I am doing wrong in my second implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution myself.

'component' => array('highlighting' => array('**field**' =>'autocomplete')));

The parameter name of highlighting component is field but I had used **fields**.